# How can i split the id numbers for cart items after increasing quantity

Tags: php, jquery, html

I upgraded this functionality to update the quantity number if i click on the up arrow or down arrow. Before i had a submit button next to the quantity number and it would update. But now, if i have 2 cart items it mixes the 2 id's together and that creates a new cart item instead of updating the quantity number of 1 Id number. How can i fix this with the below code.

```
$('#quantity').on('input', function() {
  // get basic information for updating the cart
  var id = $('.update-quantity-form').find('.product-id').text();
  var quantity = $('.update-quantity-form').find('.cart-quantity').val();

  // redirect to update_quantity.php, with parameter values to process the request
  window.location.href = "update_quantity.php?id=" + id + "&quantity=" + quantity;
  return false;
});
});

This is the php/html code:

  //update quantity
              echo "<form class='update-quantity-form'>";
                  echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
                  echo "<div class='input-group'>";
                      echo "<input id='quantity' type='number' name='quantity' value='{$quantity}' class='form-control cart-quantity' min='1' />";
                      echo "</div>";
              echo "</form>";
```

So if i have product id number 40 and product number 41, it takes them both like id=4041. How can i change this in a way that it will take only the product id where i increase the quantity on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#quantity').on('input', function() {
    // get basic information for updating the cart
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var quantity = $(this).val();

    // redirect to update_quantity.php, with parameter values to process the request
    window.location.href = "update_quantity.php?id=" + id + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    return false;
});

<form class='update-quantity-form'>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <input id='quantity' type='number' name='quantity' rel='{id}' value='{quantity}' class='form-control cart-quantity' min='1' />
    </div>
</form>
```

You can test here [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd2ntr0x/1/)

Comment: Only the first product item works now, the second doesn't update. I had to say that the php/html code is inside a `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);`

Comment: O i fixed it, i removed the id from the input and used the class for jquery.

Comment: Ok good, On the jsFiddle link I had made an example with two items.